# Derive from class template which is nested in class template, all withing a class template

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, crtp

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
template<template<typename> class... Attributes>
struct Skills
{
    template<class DERIVED>
    struct Create : public Attributes<DERIVED>...
    {};
};

template <class T, class SKILLS>
class Tester : public typename SKILLS::Create<Tester<T,SKILLS>>
{}
```

but the compiler complains with:

*error C2518: keyword 'typename' illegal in base class list; ignored*

This works fine if I don't derive within a class template, however.

**Is there any chance to derive from the nested template class?**

Why do I need that? I'm trying to implement a nicer interface for a CRTP-class template, which allows doing something like:

```
using MyClass = ClassWithAttributes<Skills<Plus,Minus,Equal,Clear,Size>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write

```
template <class T, class SKILLS>
class Tester : public SKILLS::template Create<Tester<T,SKILLS>>
{ };
```

I mean

(1) no `typename`: in the list of base classes is implicit that the arguments are types

(2) you need `template`, before `Create`

(3) use `SKILLS` as argument of `Tester`, not `Skills`, because you have declared the template parameter `SKILLS`

(4) remember the semicolon at the end of class definition

Comment: Thank you, that was it. The (3) was just a typo, I edited this.